# Wrong variable data type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, office365, smp

I have class, which intended to grab user name and his email from Git commits:

```
class BitbucketData(object):

    def get_user_name(self):

        proc = subprocess.Popen("git --no-pager show -s --format='%an'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        committer_name = proc.stdout.read()

        if committer_name:
            return committer_name

    def get_user_email(self):

        proc = subprocess.Popen("git --no-pager show -s --format='%aE'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        committer_email = proc.stdout.read()

        if committer_email:
            return committer_email
```

It used then to send notifications for users (bottom is working version - without variables - all `sender` and `receiver` data set explicitly, not in variables - they commented here):

```
class Services(object):


    def sendmail(self, event):

        repo = BitbucketData()

        #to_address = repo.get_user_email()
        #to_address = 'user@domain.com'
        #to_name = repo.get_user_name()
        #to_name = 'Test user'

        subject = 'Bamboo build and deploy ready'
        sender = 'Bamboo agent <user@domain.com>'

        text_subtype = 'plain'
        message = """
        Hello, {}.

        Your build ready.
        Link to scenario: URL
        Link to build and deploy results: {})

        """.format('Test user', os.environ['bamboo_resultsUrl'])

        msg = MIMEText(message, text_subtype)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = 'Test user <user@domain.com>'

        smtpconnect = smtplib.SMTP('outlook.office365.com', 587)
        smtpconnect.set_debuglevel(1)
        smtpconnect.starttls()
        smtpconnect.login('user@domain.com', 'password')
        smtpconnect.sendmail('user@domain.com', 'user@domain.com', msg.as_string())
        smtpconnect.quit()

        print('Mail sent')

        print(repo.get_user_email())
```

Problem is - if I'm using data from variables (e.g. `to_address = 'user@domain.com'` or using `BitbucketData()` class with `to_address = repo.get_user_email()` - I got an error from **Office365** server:

> ```
> ...
> reply: '250 2.1.0 Sender OK\r\n'
> reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Sender OK
> send: "rcpt TO:<'user@domain.com'>\r\n"
> reply: '501 5.1.3 Invalid address\r\n'
> reply: retcode (501); Msg: 5.1.3 Invalid address
> ...
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
>     raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
> smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {"'user@domain.com'\n": (501, '5.1.3 Invalid address')}
> ```

When using variables code looks like next:

```
class Services(object):


    def sendmail(self, event):

        repo = BitbucketData()

        to_address = repo.get_user_email()
        #to_address = 'user@domain.com'
        to_name = repo.get_user_name()
        #to_name = 'Test user'
        from_address = 'user@domain.com'

        subject = 'Bamboo build and deploy ready'
        sender = 'Bamboo agent <user@domain.com>'

        text_subtype = 'plain'
        message = """
        Hello, {}.

        Your build ready.
        Link to scenario: URL
        Link to build and deploy results: {})

        """.format(to_name, os.environ['bamboo_resultsUrl'])

        msg = MIMEText(message, text_subtype)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = to_name

        smtpconnect = smtplib.SMTP('outlook.office365.com', 587)
        smtpconnect.set_debuglevel(1)
        smtpconnect.starttls()
        smtpconnect.login('user@domain.com', 'password')
        smtpconnect.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
        smtpconnect.quit()

        print('Mail sent')

        print(repo.get_user_email())
```

What I'm (or Microsoft SMTP...) doing wrong here?

UPD

```
def sendmail(self, event):

    repo = BitbucketData()
    print(repr(repo.get_user_email()))
    ...
```

Gives me:

> ```
> ...
> Creating new AutoEnv config
> "'user@domain.com'\n"
> send: 'ehlo pc-user.kyiv.domain.net\r\n'
> ...
> ```

Comment: can you print and update `print(repr(repo.get_user_email()))` in the question?

Comment: Did you notice that `"'user@domain.com'\n"` from your error code is a double wrapped string? That value actually contains quotes and a newline character, so it's probably not a valid address (unless the error code added the extra characters).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan yup, I seen it - but can't understood from where " " appears :-|

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks, question updated. And yes - there is `" "` again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes and stripping the newline when you pass it as a parameter? Like this `theEmail.replace('"','').strip()`, you could see if that works. It wont solve the source of the problem but it will let you know if that's the exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are receiving the following as output from your git commands -

```
"'user@domain.com'\n"
```

You are directly passing this to smtpconnect, which is causing the issue, as this is not a valid email address. You probably need to get the actual string from it. One way to get it is to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function for that . Example -

```
>>> import ast
>>> e = ast.literal_eval("'user@domain.com'\n")
>>> print(e)
user@domain.com
```

You would need to do this when returning the email from the `get_user_email()` function . Most probably `committer_name` also has this issue, so you may want to do this for that as well.

---

From documentation of `ast.literal_eval()` -

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But - can it be done with `re.sub`, may be? I'm playing with it right now.

Comment: I guess it can be, but I am not an expert in regular expression :) . And I am guessing it would be a complex regular expression.